# User dynamic consents

Tags: identityserver4

I'm building a SCA for our environments using IdentityServer4.
Now each user have one or more unique resources that I want to be displayed on the consent screen for the user to give consent to be able to read in our environments.

I'm using IS4 EF for data storage.
And I've added some endpoints for adding data to the database. 
But I'm some what confused on how to continue.

Should there be a universal scope for accounts? Or one scope for each account?
Can a user have multiple claims of the same name but with different data?

What are the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you've build so far, but I think you are making things complicated.

Think of a resource as a logical group of 1 to n api's. Where each api can implement 1 to n scopes. A scope can refer to a service that has certain functionality.

Suppose you have the `Api1` resource. And you have the scopes `Contacts` and `Messages`. This means that your resource (which can be a group of 1 to n Api's) has functionality to do something with contacts and something with messages. Where the scopes can be implemented anywhere within the resource. You can create one api that implements all scopes, two api's that each implement one scope, use multiple api's that implements parts and pieces of the scopes or link to an external api. This will make no difference for the user.

Please note that it depends whether you need `contacts.read` and `contacts.write` or just `contacts`. Because in the first case read/write is not authorization but rather a logical seperation of services. While in the second case authorization can determine the read/write access.

The user has access to the resource using your application. In order to grant the application access to the resource (as the client is requesting information on behalf of this user), the user has to give consent.

If the user doesn't want to, then the client is not allowed to access the resource on behalf of the user and the service cannot be fully executed. So if you don't want to share your contacts, then the user has to provide the information in another way, or simply do not offer the service as requirements are not available.

On the other hand the user is a resource as well, as the UserClaims contain information about the user. So the user resource can have scopes as well, like openid, profile, email, address. If the user doesn't give consent to use the profile, then the information has to be acquired another way, similar to the situation for the api resource.

But there are differences between scopes. Openid for instance is a required scope, as it contains (at least) the sub claim, needed to identify the user. This is a minimal requirement that therefor can't be revoked. The only alternative for the user is to click `No Thanks`, which means that the user chooses not to use the application.

So you have an api and a client (e.g. mvc application). The api can have 1 to n scopes and the mvc application can request 1 to n scopes (from both api and user resource).

You can extend IdentityServer to act as a resource as well. And by that I don't mean endpoints, but as an actual api. You can even create a seperate api for that. Simply configure the api, add scopes and configure the client.

Suppose I add the IdApi as resource and a scope `Account`. This scope is for all users available, but using resource based authorization you can determine the exact level of access the user (and thus the application) has. You can choose to set the scope as required.

So account can't be user bound, as the scope is a child of a resource. Don't confuse scopes with roles. A scope has nothing to do with authorization itself. Scopes are requested by the client, while roles are user bound. And yes, you can add multiple claims with from same type, e.g. role=admin, role=manager. This will result in a collection of roles. But this is not something you need in this case.

Both api and identity scopes are used as filter for the userclaims. In case of profile, all claims that match a type in the list of allowed claim types will be added to the token, provided that the client requested the scope.

The api verifies the resource name (aud), and not the scope name. In order to check for scopes you can use events, middleware and policies.

If you let me know whether this answer helps you or if additional information is needed, then I can update the answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. First of all I want to ask you since you mention it: If I extend identityserver with a controller so it becomes an api(apiresource). How do I use it to protect itself? I tried with AddJwtBearer but then I break the oidc-login.

Comment: And second: Why can't a scope not be user bound? User1 got account1 and account2. While user2 got account3 and account4. User1 don't give client1 access to account1.

Comment: Like explained, a scope defines a part of the resource and a client can request the scope. So how is it user bound? The user can't give a client access, the access is configured. All the user can do is give its consent to the client to access the resource on its behalf. But that is not limited to user1. So it seems accountx isn't a scope at all. How do you configure accountx?

Comment: Add the Jwt Bearer authentication handler as described here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html And make sure that you mark the controller with the scheme: `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`. You can also add the api as endpoint: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html

Comment: I get what scope should be in the context of STS. But in my case I need to create a consent page where the user1 gives consent to account1 or/and account2. And since the consent page only displays scopes I need account1 and account2 act as scopes, breaking out of the original role of a scope.

Comment: This is just presentation. You can customize the consent page. Currently it has two blocks: IdentityScopes and ResourceScopes. Why don't you add a CustomScopes block?

Comment: Huh what are CustomScopes? IdentityScopes are IdentityResource and ResourceScopes are ApiResources?

Comment: nvm found it in the docs. So thats what I'm trying to do atm. I'm adding user1's account1 and account2 as custom scopes. But then I also need to add the scopes as allowed for the client. Which is fine, but how do I add the scopes for the client so when it calls the authorization_url. The redirecturi includes the account1 and account2 scopes??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183206/discussion-between-ruard-van-elburg-and-president-camacho).